# How to use different group separators for thousands and millions. Oracle

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

I need to display different results in the next format, example:

40000000  to 40'000,000

I tried using this,  but when i try 2 differents group separators i get the "invalid number format model" error:

```
select to_char(9999999999, '9g999g99999g9', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')
from dual;
```

Also tried using substr and replace but it doesnt work in all the cases (like when the result is 3000000 or 700000000).
This works but it is not the optimal solution.:

```
SELECT substr(replace('40,000,000',',',''''),0,length(40000000)-2)|| substr('40,000,000',-4) from dual;
```

What the actual select look like if i use the previous code.

```
SELECT substr(replace(to_char(oTOTAL_SENIOR, '999,999,999'),',',''''),0,length(oTOTAL_SENIOR)-2)|| substr(to_char(oTOTAL_SENIOR, '999,999,999'),-4) from dual
```

The previous select gets bugged when i use substr replace and to_char together because of the '999,999,999'.

I also tried using regexp_replace but im not good at it.
I know i need to replace everything but the last 4 characters (,000) but i dont know how.

Any help will be aprreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need someone smarter than me to do that properly, but - meanwhile, see whether this helps.

I'm on XE 11g; in order to avoid "no more data to read from socket" error I got during the final steps of this query (I believe it was due to two string reversings), I created my own "reverse" function. There's *undocumented* `reverse` function, but I don't want to use it.

Basically, it reverses a string you pass as a parameter. What do I need it for? I found it simpler to reverse values, split them to 3-by-3-by-3 characters and apply those "strange" separators you want. Also, it makes the whole code *simpler*. It can be done without it, but - as I said - *no more data to read from socket* won't allow it. Sorry about that.

Now, someone will say: why didn't you (meaning: me, LF) do that using PL/SQL completely and put *everything* into a function? No particular reason & no problem in doing it, if necessary.

OK, here it is:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_reverse (par_string in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    retval varchar2(20);
  5  begin
  6    select listagg(substr(par_string, level, 1))
  7           within group (order by level desc)
  8      into retval
  9      from dual
 10      connect by level <= length(par_string);
 11
 12    return retval;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_reverse('1234') from dual;

F_REVERSE('1234')
---------------------------------------------------------------------
4321

SQL>
```

Finally, this is what you want:

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, 40100200 from dual union all
  3     select 2,  2300400 from dual union all
  4     select 3,   700500 from dual union all
  5     select 4,    25700 from dual union all
  6     select 5,     6300 from dual union all
  7     select 6,      555 from dual
  8    )
  9  select id,
 10    regexp_replace(
 11                    f_reverse(
 12                      substr(f_reverse(col), 1, 3) ||','||
 13                      substr(f_reverse(col), 4, 3) || chr(39) ||
 14                      substr(f_reverse(col), 7)
 15                      ), '^[^0-9]+', '') result
 16  from test;

        ID RESULT
---------- ----------
         1 40'100,200
         2 2'300,400
         3 700,500
         4 25,700
         5 6,300
         6 555

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- lines #1 - 7 - sample data
- lines #9 onward is useful code
- lines #12 - 14 - splitting reversed sample data into substrings 3 characters in length

  - line #12 - concatenated `,` as this is *thousands* separator
  - line #13 - concatenaded `chr(13)` which is `'`, a *millions* separator
- line #11 - reversing concatenated "reversed" string back
- line #10 - removing possible non-numeric characters from the beginning of the result (those are separators for values that are shorter than "thousand" or "million")

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your reverse function is working with a regexp_replace code i had.
Im also applying your solution to my problem, is not "short" but works. Thanks